# Assigning specific app service access to Azure active directory user

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, azureportal

I have created one Active Directory user in Azure portal, now I want to allow this user to access only one app service (Start/Stop/Change settings etc.), I am not able to figure out how to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [role-based access control (RBAC)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/quickstart-assign-role-user-portal) to do it.

Make sure the user is in the subscription, navigate to the app service in the portal -> Access control (IAM)-> Add.